# Listview.builder creating duplicate items on flutter

Tags: listview, flutter, dynamic, duplicates, widget

I'm creating a dynamic list of widgets, but every time I add another one it duplicates, when I add 2 item it'll become 4 when I add 3 it'll become 9 and so on... I've been searching over the net for possible causes and I think it's very similar to this [Flutter JSON duplicate index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52288865/flutter-json-duplicate-index)  I think I'm missing something in this code, I don't know where to put the r, please help

```
child: Container(
      height: 250,
      child: new ListView.builder(
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: newList.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {

            final r = newList[index];

            return new Row(
              children: newList,
            );
          }),
    ),
  );
```

here is my delared newList:

```
List<Widget> newList = [];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have itemCount of list set to newList length.The itemBuilder code runs x amount of times the length is.So in itemBuilder you need to pass index to newList you are showing otherwise it will show all List.

```
child: Container(
          height: 250,
          child: new ListView.builder(
              physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: newList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                final r = newList[index];

                return new Row(
                  children: newList[index],
                );
              }),
        ),
      );
```

Comment: thanks for looking into this, I tried using your code but it shows

The argument type 'Widget' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Widget>'

Comment: It's because a Row takes List of Widgets and what you have in your newList indexes is Single widgets like SizedBox(), Container().Try removing Row and return newList[index];

Comment: If you wanna pursue with Row try this : return Row(children: <Widget>[  newList[index]  , ]
  );